# Adding Media Library to Blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, superuser-blog

The Gaming.StackExchange blog currently has a "Media Library", with an easy method for uploading multiple images to the blog. Currently we do not have this feature on Super User, and it is difficult to upload images. The media library also avoids using 3rd party sites, like Dropbox, Tinypic, etc.

[image: Media Library]

Comment: Wait... we don't have an insert image button for the blog, or the site? Because I believe there's one on both...?

Comment: @DMA Let me change that, appears we have it now!

Comment: <strike>OK, I still don't get "Adding Media Library to Blog"... the blog already has a media library - you've even given a screenshot of it!</strike> No, that's Gaming's one. SU has one too, you need your account permissions changing.

Comment: This is due to how the wordpress permissions are set up. Ask Rebecca Chernoff if you need your account to be modified to allow image uploads. She said she made a fix for that permissions problem.

Comment: @nhinkle I shall ask her in chat then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon's status was Contributor, which in all fairness was really pathetically low. I've upgraded him to Editor, given that he's already proven to be a very worth blogger!

Problem solved!